What exactly it is meant by "electrons stored" and why is it not a constant for linear profile?
These are screenshots from Microelectronics by Behzad Razavi


It is been seen that for a linear decrease in the electron density the "the total electrons stored" depends upon the length of the bar(here L) and is equal to aNL. In contrast, for an exponential profile it is constant, equal to aNLd(d in the subscript).

But,shouldnt the value be a constant for both and equal to the total electrons injected ?
I am confused

To comply with the site rules for How to reference material written by others please [edit] the question to give the source of the images.
